# How to set starting page in WatchKit PageController

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have a page controller WatchKit app where I am inserting a new page. I want to set the default page that is displayed to the index I was on before the refresh, but I can't figure out how to set which page is selected first (it always defaults to the page at index 0). Here is how I am refreshing them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.models.count; i++)
{
    [names addObject:@"MyInterfaceController"];
    [objects addObject:self.models[i]];
}

[WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:names contexts:objects];
```

Does anyone know how to set the selected page programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial order is determined by the order of your `names` and `contexts` when you call `reloadRootControllers`. However, you can make use of the `becomeCurrentPage` method on `WKInterfaceController` to change the current page.

Check out the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/becomeCurrentPage

Answer (score 3):

watchOS 4 now has a method for what you want. Check out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2868441-reloadrootpagecontrollers

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: names,
                                                contexts: contexts, 
                                                orientation: .horizontal, 
                                                pageIndex: startPageIndex)
```

As you might have guessed, the last parameter is the index of the start-page. Works without animations, just what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that at this time, I'm afraid.  At best, as outlined by [bgilham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704092/bgilham), you can have your app launch to page 0, and animate to another.  But that doesn't sound like the kind of behavior you are looking for at all.